# OctoberCMS builder plugin form columns in backend

Tags: octobercms

It's possible to implement three columns to forms creation with plugin builder in OctoberCMS?

Comment: no, i guess they provide either full or half, you can add custom css. but builder will not provide it i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely control the UX of forms in builder at least three different ways:

1. Modify the view in the controller relevant for the Create, Update portions of your form (this can be found in the controller folder of your Plugin Folder that Builder created for you.

*Screen shot of the "controllers" folder for my example plugin "linkexhange"  showing where to find the form view for my CRUD known as "links":*
[image]

2. Use a partial field to inject CSS (< style>), JS or other HTML
3. Modify the cms.php config file to override the Backend Style with your own CSS/JS etc (hard work, not for the timid)

*Screen shot of part of the config file where you can override the backend CSS and JS or extend it.
in this case my Plugin Namespace is **BusinessTech** and I have a Plugin I made called **BackendSkin***
[image]